# Create date and time picker in one dialog in android

Tags: android, dialog

As in question title i want to display a date and time picker in one dialog in android. Maybe display first datepicker, after user select a date it should transitate timepicker without closing and reopen the dialog.

How to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use thar library with Material Design on Pre-Lollipop devices, it's so beautiful Library.

https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker

Time picker it's amazing.

Comment: If you had only tried the library you'd know if it solves your question, instead of just to vote no, trying to prove the suggestions of users for that we are. Yo can do all what you need with that library, but... forget it....

Comment: I've checked the code and tried the apk and dosen't contain what i asked for. Its just a wrapper for the android lollipop dialog - still great, but as i said, it dosen't answer my question. And btw sorry for your downvote but wasn't me. If you have any suitable answer please feel free to edit. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

//my style of date and time picker 
//datepicker

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat,timeFormat;
dateFormat =new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MMM d");
timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
```

//my onclick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.dob){
        openDatePicker(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
                String dateString=formatDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                dob.setText(dateString);
            }
        });
    }
```

// opendatepicker method

```
private  String formatDate(long timeStamp){
    Date date =new Date(timeStamp);
    String dateToShow = dateFormat.format(date);
    return dateToShow;
}
private void openDatePicker(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listner){
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    new DatePickerDialog(this,listner,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}
```

//and time picker

```
if (v.getId()==R.id.time){
        openTimePicker(new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                String time=getStringTime(hourOfDay,minute);
                textTime.setText(time);
            }
        });
    }
```

//opentimepickermethod

```
private void openTimePicker(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listner){
    Date date=new Date();
    new TimePickerDialog(this,listner,date.getHours(),date.getMinutes(),false).show();
}

private String getStringTime(int hour,int minute){
    String am_pm="";
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==Calendar.AM){
        am_pm="AM";
        return ""+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+""+am_pm;
    }else{
        am_pm="PM";
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)==0) {
            hour = 12;
            return "" + hour + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "" + am_pm;
        }else
            return ""+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+""+am_pm;

    }

}
```